# Adding new field in table and calling it is giving -- NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using a legacy database and I have a table called TEAM_PLAYER.

I added a new field to it called player_note and in my viewdetails.html.erb, i added the following line of code to retrieve the note associated with a player.

```
<label>Player Note:</label> <span> <%=h @teamplayer.player_note %> </span><br/><br/>
```

However i am getting 'undefined method `player_note' for #'

Am i missing something?? Note that I am not using the dbase migration coz i am already using a legacy database.

Thanks for any hints provided.

Comment: Can you show the snippet of code where you're actually making sure this field is in the model? if you aren't doing it via a migration, I'm not entirely clear what you mean by "I added a new field to it called player_note"

Comment: Er, there is nowhere in the code i made sure this field is in the model..i just modified the existing table 'TEAM_PLAYER' to add this new column and in my 'viewdetails.html.erb' page, am referring to the newly added field as '@teamplayer.player_note'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note that I am not using the dbase migration coz i am already using a legacy database.

But you said -

> I added a new field to it called player_note

then why no migration?

Also you need to restart your rails application for newly added column to take effect.

Comment: Restarted the rails app, problem still persisting

Comment: Which db you are using? a stack trace of error would be good.

Comment: Got it, i deleted the application from netbeans and added it again..now it seems to work...that's strange though

Comment: netbeans adds a nbproject folder under the project root directory, maybe that had retained some bad configs.